# Entering Date/Time into ACCESS DB with ASP.NET(C#)

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2007

I want to enter a DATE to my ACCESS DB, the field is DATE/TIME.
The user enter it in a form in this method (text) DD/MM/YYYY

The code:
DATE/TIME object

```
DateTime Bday = new DateTime(long.Parse(Request.Form["Bday"]));
```

The SQL QUERY:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO (Fname,Lname,User,Pass,Email,BiDate,IsAdmin,IsMale) VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + user + "','" + pass + "','" + email + "',#" + Bday + "#," + admin + "," + male + ")";
```

**Its not working**

Comment: Much better to use parameters.

Comment: I fixed the SQL QUERY but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `long.Parse` part

```
        DateTime Bday = DateTime.ParseExact(Request.Form["Bday"], "dd/MM/yyyy", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO (Fname,Lname,[User],Pass,Email,BiDate,"
        +"IsAdmin,IsMale) " + 
        "VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + user + "','" + pass + "','"
        + email + "',#" + Bday.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "#," + admin + "," + male + ")";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are going to run into locale problems. Access will see a string date as US when there is ambiguity.

Comment: I get a :"Cannot convert from string to Long" erroe

Comment: sorry I forgot DateTime.Parse

Comment: But you'll have to validate the user input as this code will throw an exception if the user inputs the date in the wrong format.

Comment: Thank you so much.@mortb
But now he says i have a problem with th query:
    INSERT INTO users (Fname,Lname,IsAdmin,BiDate,IsMale,User,Pass,Email) VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "'," + admin + ", #" + Bday.ToString("d") + "#,"+male+",'"+user+"','"+pass+"','"+email+"')"

Comment: I added [] around user which will help if it is a reserved word problem.